# How to display varible value in parameter on the html page?

Tags: post, get, parameter-passing

suppose i want redirect to another page using some parameters like given in following html code

link to page2

whenever we click on this link my browser goes to

http://localhost:8080/cloud/page2.jsp?id=2489&user=tom

then i want to display the value of id & user parameter to next page

what should i do??????

i got solution in php as

echo $_GET['id']; // output 2489

But i want solution in JSP or in html

Answer (score 0):

**Use request.getParameter() method.**

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));

System.out.println(request.getParameter("user"));
```

**in jsp page**

```
<%= request.getParameter("id")%>

<%= request.getParameter("user")%>
```

Comment: i used <%= request.getParameter("id")%> this code but still it shows me null on the jsp page...... :-(